# how to compute the connction form of conformal metric using moving frame?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I know using natural coordinate to compute the relation ship between $M,g $ and $ (M,\phi^2g)$; using the orthornormal frame can also do the computation, both using the kozul formula.

However , i want to find the third different proof of the relation ship between the connecton form with respect ot conformal metric and the original metric.

what i have done is as follows:

$ M,e_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot e_n $ be the orthornormal frame of $ g $,
$ M,,\omega^1 \cdot\cdot\cdot \omega^n $ be the  orthornormal  dual frame of $ g $
$ M,\frac{1}{\phi}e_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{1}{\phi}e_n $ be the orthornormal frame of $ \phi ^2g $,
$ M,,\tilde{\omega}^1 \cdot\cdot\cdot \tilde{\omega}^n $ be the  orthornormal  dual frame of $ g $, we know that
$$ \tilde{\omega}^i=\phi \omega^i $$
then we use the cartan's structure equartion,

$$d\omega^i=\omega_j^i\wedge \omega^j $$
$$d\tilde{\omega}^i=\tilde{\omega}_j^i\wedge \tilde{\omega}^j $$

so, we get

\begin{align}
   d\tilde{\omega}^i&=d(\phi \omega^i)\\
  & =d\phi\wedge \omega^i+\phi d\omega^i\\
   &=d\phi \wedge\omega^i+\phi \omega_j^i\wedge \omega^j\\
   &=\tilde{\omega}_j^i\wedge \tilde{\omega}^j\\
   &=\phi \tilde{\omega}_j^i\wedge \omega^j
  \end{align}
thus ,we get
\begin{align}
 \phi (\tilde{\omega}_j^i- \omega_j^i)\wedge \omega^j=d\phi \wedge  \omega^i
\end{align}

Now , I have used the cartan lemma, find the result is far away the  correct answer. I have also using the formula action on the bivector
$e_i \wedge e_j$ ,find alway lost the symmetric part

using the moving frame,  what I what to find is  :

$$\tilde{\omega}_j^i- \omega_j^i=? $$

recently , i can just find the two term of the right answer, lost one term. I have doubt that the moving frame cannot be used to solve this problem or I have made some mistakes.

Any answer is quite hepful and will be appriciated.I have suffered a lot.**strong text**

Comment: First, you’re missing the wedge in $d\phi\wedge \omega^i$. Second, forget about evaluating on vectors. Just finish once you get to the Cartan lemma set-up. Maybe write $d\\phi = \sum\phi_j\omega^j$?

Comment: Unless you provide further steps, you’re not going to get help. You claim to have done things and expect us to be mind-readers.